Reputation leagues show phantom winners when nobody has earned reputation
The stack exchange reputation leagues show for each site the top reputation earners by week, month, quarter, year, and all time.
For example, for Community Building:

We can view statistics per site when looking at the details:

No users earned reputation on Community Building this week.  Nothing exceptional, it's a quiet site.  But then how did the user "hairboat" turn up as number one?  This user has never earned any reputation on Community Building Stack Exchange.  But they used to work at Stack Overflow.  Did they programme the reputation leagues and put in their own user as a placeholder winner?  Or does the user with the lowest non-zero ID win?

"Did they programme the reputation leagues and put in their own user as a placeholder winner?" Yes, this is a sleeper cell of the SE Inc shadow government. /s

Possible duplicate of 2015 Discrepancy in Stats for StackOverflow's Top Users by Week, Month, Quarter, or Year created in 2015.

@Rubén Seems like two different bugs to me.

Additional data: this week's winner for [Freelancing.SE] is user ID 22571.
